# Working and handling data in D3 and Plotly

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, ecmascript-6, plotly

I have to do data manipulation so I can draw a line plot in plotlyjs. Basically a line chart with 6 trends.

I have three csv data files:

```
overall.csv
overall with state.csv
overall with school and state.csv
```

**overall.csv** looks like this:

```
date, admission, dropout
```

**overall with state.csv** looks like:

```
date, state, admission, dropouts
```

**overall with school and state.csv** looks like:

```
date, school, state, admission dropouts
```

I have to do data manipulation so I can draw a line plot in plotlyjs. So the plot of data that I need to do is:

Plot 6 different trends:

1. Overall admission **(overall.csv)**
2. Overall dropouts **(overall.csv)**
3. 'X' state admissions **(overall with state.csv)**
4. 'X' state dropouts **(overall with state.csv)**
5. 'Y' school admissions **(overall with school and state.csv)**
6. 'Y' School dropouts **(overall with school and state.csv)**

Overall 6 different trends over time.

I put up a code but am confused as I don't have a background in javascript, but it the code doesn't work, I keep getting an empty array.

```
var test = [];

d3.csv('overall.csv')
  .then(data => {
  data.map(function(d) {
  //console.log(d.admissions);
  test.push(d.admissions)
})});

console.log(test);
```

I keep getting an empty array.

Comment: I think you need to include  a bit more detail on what code you're using.

Comment: `d3.csv` is asynchronous. Have a look at the first answer in the duplicate target (the *"this question already has answers here"* link) to understand why `test` was empty.